# Android Download Zip (That can change name on the server)

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to make android download a zip file from my web server using a php page to download it.

If I download using a static link to the zip file, it works great, but i'm trying to download using a php file with this code:

```
function file_list($d,$x){
   foreach(array_diff(scandir($d,1),array('.','..')) as $f)if(is_file($d.'/'.$f)&&(($x)?ereg($x.'$',$f):1))$l[]=$f;
   return $l;
}

$arr = file_list("../download/",".zip");

$filename = $arr[0];
$filepath = "../download/".$arr[0];

if(!file_exists($filepath)){
   die('Error: File not found.');
} else {
   // Set headers
   header("Cache-Control: public");
   header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
   header("Content-Type: application/zip");
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

   readfile($filepath);
}
```

If I access the php file in my browser, it downloads the zip just great!

Now, in the Android side, it downloads like it's supposed but the name of the zip is getZip.php (php file name) and the file size is 22.

This is the code that does the downloading stuff on the Android

```
        int count;

        try {
            downloadCoords();
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lengthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Length of file: " + lengthOfFile);

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
            if(!f.isDirectory()){
                f.mkdirs();
            }

            Uri u = Uri.parse(url.toString());
            File uf = new File(""+u);
            zipname = uf.getName();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Zipname: " + zipname);

            File zipSDCARD = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+zipname);
            if(!zipSDCARD.isFile()){
                Log.d("zipSDCARD.isFile()","false");

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + zipname);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lengthOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            }
            successDownload = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            successDownload = false;
            Log.e("Error","DownloadZip",e);
        }
```

What needs to be done, is getting the zipname correctly and the ziplength too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, if applicable to your situation you could make use of the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) . This will handle all the nitty gritty stuff of downloading (like retries etc) for you.

Comment: @Renard I don't really know if that will help, I think it will achieve the exactly same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it using php to write a link to the zip dynamically to the screen using this script:

```
function file_list($d,$x){
    foreach(array_diff(scandir($d,1),array('.','..')) as $f)if(is_file($d.'/'.$f)&&(($x)?ereg($x.'$',$f):1))$l[]=$f;
    return $l;
}

$arr = file_list("../download/",".zip");

$filename = $arr[0];
$filepath = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/download/".$arr[0];
print($filepath);
```

Then on the android, I used a BufferedReader to get the link correctly:

```
private String getZipURL(){
    String result = "";
    InputStream is = null;
    try{
        String url = ZipURL;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

        int timeoutSocket = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("getZipURL", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        return null;
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result=sb.toString();
        return result;
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("convertZipURL", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

It may seem wrong, but it works as I want. I posted the code so I can get a workaround for someone with the same problem. Thanks!